# Iplayer downloads

Tags: get-iplayer

Until recently I have been able to download programs from BBC Iplayer using the following in my terminal: `get_iplayer --pid=xxxx`
where "xxxx" is the program id from Iplayer. However,now I am getting the following error message.

```
WARNING: rdf URL contained no data
WARNING: PID URL contained no RDF data. Trying to record PID directly.
INFO: Trying pid: b08qsm5n using type: tv
INFO: Trying to stream pid using type tv
INFO: pid not found in tv cache
Matches:

INFO: 1 Matching Programmes
WARNING: Could not download programme metadata from http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b08qsm5n.xml
ERROR: Failed to get version pid metadata from iplayer site
```

Any ideas what I can do to get the downloads working again please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just open the link and read:

"Maintenance mode

From April 18, 2017, the BBC is no longer able to offer XML, RDF and iCalendar (.ics) views of programme metadata from this location.

Work is underway in some areas of the BBC with a view to providing a durable successor to the decommissioned data views, and when the shape of this work is known, suitable communications will be put in place to direct the wider technology community towards that successor. [...]"

Answer (score 0):

There's an update to get-iplayer to resolve this - head over to https://squarepenguin.co.uk/ for up-to-the-minute get-iplayer support; you can either install the latest version manually, or use the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~jon-hedgerows/+archive/ubuntu/get-iplayer

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend to [edit] this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)